# iOS - Storyboard: Buttons are not clickable after Xcode update (6.1 to later)

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, uistoryboard

**I have the following problem:**

If I load a (functional) project created in Xcode 6.1 or earlier to later versions of Xcode and run the project, everything works right... **until the first edit of Storyboard**. After that some buttons stop working (are not clickable anymore).

If I compare **Main_iPhone.storyboard** xml file before and after editing there are only two differences:

1) Tools version identification - as expected.

2) Attribute `ambiguous="YES"` disappears from the parent view of the affected buttons.

I'm not sure what for is this attribute and most importantly I'm unable to force Xcode to leave the attribute be where it is or fix the buttons to work without it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you check your button's binds & z-index? I'd advice to double check the reference to your controller, the events and their handlers, and make sure their places in the view hierarchy make them at the top of other elements or layers. Newer versions of XCode update your storyboard at the first opening, thus leading to unpredictable behaviors sometimes.